# ¿Cómo enviar el foco de un Spinner a otro Spinner de Otra Activity?

Tags: android-studio, spinner

Pues cada vez que trabajo en una actividad hace la seleccion correcta y guarda en un web Services correctamente, al momento de dar click para direccionar a otra actividad y selecciono el Spinner, manda el pierde de foco. Como dando a entender que se quedó en la actividad anterior.

```
1383-1537/system_process W/InputMethodManagerService: Window alreadyfocused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@a762ecd8 attribute=null


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_info_general);

    Date d = new Date();

    lblNombreEjecutivo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblNombreEjecutivo);
    lblNoReporte = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblNoReporte);
    lblFecha = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblFecha);
    UnidadVentas = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spUnidadVentas);
    MedidaReclamo = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spMedidaReclamo);
    ProblemaPresent = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spProblemaPresent);
    Muestras = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spMuestras);
    Visita = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spVisita);
    btnReporte= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReporte);
    txtNombreTienda = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNombreTienda);
    txtNombreCliente = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNombreCliente);
    txtTelefonoContacto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtTelefonoContacto);
    txtEmail =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
    txtCodigoProcudto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCodigoProcudto);
    txtNoLote = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNoLote);
    txtCantidadReclamada=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCantidadReclamada);
    txtExistencia = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtExistencia);
    txtAdicional = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtAdicional);
    txtDireccion = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDireccion);


    //SACAMOS LA FECHA COMPLETA
    SimpleDateFormat fecc = new SimpleDateFormat("d, MMMM 'del' yyyy");
    String fechacComplString = fecc.format(d);
    lblFecha.setText(fechacComplString);

    //Spiner de Unidad de Ventas
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.UnidadVentas, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    UnidadVentas.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Spiner de Medidad de Reclamos
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.MedidaReclamo, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    MedidaReclamo.setAdapter(adapter2);

    //Spiner de Problema Presentado
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter3 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.ProblemaPresent, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    ProblemaPresent.setAdapter(adapter3);

    //Spiner de Muestras Presentadas
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter4 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Respuesta, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter4.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    Muestras.setAdapter(adapter4);

    //Spiner de Visita
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter5 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Respuesta, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter5.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    Visita.setAdapter(adapter5);


    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    lblNombreEjecutivo.setText( bundle.getString("User"));
    lblNoReporte.setText(bundle.getString("Reporte"));

    btnReporte.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(InfoGeneral.this);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            pDialog.setMessage("Agregando...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.setMax(100);
            pDialog.show();

            WSReporte tarea = new WSReporte();
            tarea.execute();
           }
    });
}

private class WSReporte extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {
    String resultado="0";

    @SuppressWarnings("WrongThread")
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        boolean result = true;

        final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://Ejemplo1.com/Reporte";
        final String METHOD_NAME = "Reporte";
        final String NAMESPACE = "http://Ejemplo1.com/";
        final String URL = "http://12.12.86.4:84/WS_CONTROL/Service1.asmx";

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        request.addProperty("canal", UnidadVentas.getSelectedItem().toString());
        request.addProperty("usuario", lblNombreEjecutivo.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("NombreTienda", txtNombreTienda.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("nombre_cliente", txtNombreCliente.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("telefono_cliente", txtTelefonoContacto.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("Email", txtEmail.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("Cod_Producto", txtCodigoProcudto.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("Lote", txtNoLote.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("Cant_Reclamada", txtCantidadReclamada.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("Medida", MedidaReclamo.getSelectedItem().toString());
        request.addProperty("Razon", ProblemaPresent.getSelectedItem().toString());
        request.addProperty("Muestras", Muestras.getSelectedItem().toString());
        request.addProperty("Visita_requerida", Visita.getSelectedItem().toString());
        request.addProperty("Direcc_Visita", txtDireccion.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("Inventario", txtExistencia.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("Observaciones", txtAdicional.getText().toString());

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try
        {
            transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive resultado_xml =(SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
            String res = resultado_xml.toString();

            resultado = res;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (result) {

            if (resultado.equals("0")) {

                Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Usuario/Clave Incorrectas.!\no .!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast1.show();

            } else {

                Intent i = new Intent(InfoGeneral.this, aplicacion.class);
                i.putExtra("Ordenes", resultado );
                i.putExtra("NoReporte", lblNoReporte.getText().toString());
                startActivity(i);

               /* int noHistory = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP;
                i.addFlags(noHistory);*/

                lblNombreEjecutivo.setText("");
                lblNoReporte.setText("");
                lblFecha.setText("");
                txtNombreTienda.setText("");
                txtNombreCliente.setText("");
                txtTelefonoContacto.setText("");
                txtEmail.setText("");
                txtCodigoProcudto.setText("");
                txtNoLote.setText("");
                txtCantidadReclamada.setText("");
                txtExistencia.setText("");
                txtAdicional.setText("");
                txtDireccion.setText("");
                lblNombreEjecutivo.setEnabled(false);
                lblNoReporte.setEnabled(false);
                lblFecha.setEnabled(false);
                txtNombreTienda.setEnabled(false);
                txtNombreCliente.setEnabled(false);
                txtTelefonoContacto.setEnabled(false);
                txtEmail.setEnabled(false);
                txtCodigoProcudto.setEnabled(false);
                txtNoLote.setEnabled(false);
                txtCantidadReclamada.setEnabled(false);
                txtExistencia.setEnabled(false);
                txtAdicional.setEnabled(false);
                txtDireccion.setEnabled(false);


            }
        } else {
            Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error en la Conexión.!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast1.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Hasta aquí termina la primera Actividad y Listo, todo bien. Luego Con la otra Actividad.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_aplicacion);

    lblCodigoOrden = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblCodigoOrden);
    lblNoReporte2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblNoReporte2);
    txtFechaSeleccionada = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtFecha) ;
    spLugarApli = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spLugarApli);
    txtDescribeApli = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDescribeApli);
    spQuienAplic = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spQuienApli);
    spPinturaExp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spPinturaExp);
    spComoApliPint = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spComoAplico);
    txtManosPintura = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtManosPintura);
    txtmsts = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtmts);
    txtCantidadUtilizada = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCantidadUtilizada);
    txtDiluyente = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDiluyente);
    txtPreparacion = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPreparacion);
    txtDescripcion = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDescripcion);
    txtCondicion = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCondicion);
    btnImagenes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnImagenes);
    btnFinalizar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFinalizar);

    txtFechaSeleccionada.setFocusable(true);
   // btnFecha = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnFecha);

    //Spinner de Lugar de Aplicacion
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(aplicacion.this, R.array.LugarAplicación, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spLugarApli.setAdapter(adapter1);



    //Spinner de Lugar de Quien Aplica
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(aplicacion.this, R.array.QuienAplica, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spQuienAplic.setAdapter(adapter2);

    //Spinner de Pintura Expuesta
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter3 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(aplicacion.this, R.array.PinturaExp, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spPinturaExp.setAdapter(adapter3);

    //Spinner de Cómo Aplicó Pintura
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter4 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(aplicacion.this, R.array.ComoAplico, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter4.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spComoApliPint.setAdapter(adapter4);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    lblCodigoOrden.setText( bundle.getString("Ordenes"));
    lblNoReporte2.setText(bundle.getString("NoReporte"));


    btnImagenes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(aplicacion.this);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            pDialog.setMessage("Procesando...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.setMax(100);
            pDialog.show();

            WSAplicacion tarea1 = new WSAplicacion();
            tarea1.execute();

        }
    });

    btnFinalizar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pDialog2 = new ProgressDialog(aplicacion.this);
            pDialog2.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            pDialog2.setMessage("Guardando...");
            pDialog2.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog2.setMax(100);
            pDialog2.show();

            WSAplicacionGuardada tarea2 = new WSAplicacionGuardada();
            tarea2.execute();

        }
    });
```

}

```
private class WSAplicacion extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {
    String resultado = "0";

    @SuppressWarnings("WrongThread")
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        boolean result = true;

        final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://Ejemplo1.com/Aplicacion";
        final String METHOD_NAME = "Aplicacion";
        final String NAMESPACE = "http://Ejemplo1.com/";
        final String URL = "http://12.12.86.4:86/WS_CONTROL/Service1.asmx";

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        request.addProperty("id_reporte", lblNoReporte2.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("aplicada_el", txtFechaSeleccionada.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("lugar_aplicacion", spLugarApli.getSelectedItem().toString());
        request.addProperty("info_aplicacion", txtDescribeApli.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("aplicador", spQuienAplic.getSelectedItem().toString());
        request.addProperty("pintura_expuesta", spPinturaExp.getSelectedItem().toString());
        request.addProperty("proceso", spComoApliPint.getSelectedItem().toString());
        request.addProperty("aplicaciones", txtManosPintura.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("mts", txtmsts.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("Cant_utilizada", txtCantidadUtilizada.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("diluyente", txtDiluyente.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("superficie_preparacion", txtPreparacion.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("descripción_superficie", txtPreparacion.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("condicion_climatica", txtCondicion.getText().toString());

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try
        {
            transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive resultado_xml =(SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
            String res = resultado_xml.toString();

            resultado = res;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }

   @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (result) {

            if (resultado.equals("0")) {

                Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Usuario/Clave Incorrectas.!\no .!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast1.show();

            } else {

                Intent i = new Intent(aplicacion.this, imagenes.class);
                i.putExtra("Ordenes", resultado );
                i.putExtra("NoReporte", lblNoReporte2.getText().toString());
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } else {
            Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error en la Conexión.!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast1.show();
        }
    }

}

private class WSAplicacionGuardada extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {
    String resultado = "0";

    @SuppressWarnings("WrongThread")
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        boolean result = true;

        final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://Ejemplo1.com/Aplicacion";
        final String METHOD_NAME = "Aplicacion";
        final String NAMESPACE = "http://Ejemplo1.com/";
        final String URL = "http://12.12.86.4:86/WS_CONTROL/Service1.asmx";

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        request.addProperty("id_reporte", lblNoReporte2.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("aplicada_el", txtFechaSeleccionada.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("lugar_aplicacion", spLugarApli.getSelectedItem().toString());
        request.addProperty("info_aplicacion", txtDescribeApli.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("aplicador", spQuienAplic.getSelectedItem().toString());
        request.addProperty("pintura_expuesta", spPinturaExp.getSelectedItem().toString());
        request.addProperty("proceso", spComoApliPint.getSelectedItem().toString());
        request.addProperty("aplicaciones", txtManosPintura.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("mts", txtmsts.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("Cant_utilizada", txtCantidadUtilizada.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("diluyente", txtDiluyente.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("superficie_preparacion", txtPreparacion.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("descripción_superficie", txtPreparacion.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("condicion_climatica", txtCondicion.getText().toString());

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try
        {
            transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive resultado_xml =(SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
            String res = resultado_xml.toString();

            resultado = res;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        pDialog2.dismiss();
        if (result) {

            if (resultado.equals("0")) {

                Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Usuario/Clave Incorrectas.!\no .!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast1.show();

            } else {

                Intent i = new Intent(aplicacion.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } else {
            Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error en la Conexión.!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast1.show();
        }
    }

}
```

Aquí el problema, al momento de utilizar los spinners de esta actividad, es cuando el logCat solo muestra que se ha perdido el foco. Mi pregunta es será que afecta al momento de cambiar de actividad pues, esta app tiene dos opciones de boton de guardar o adjuntar imagenes. Y ambas tienen la opción de que si no hizo conexión muestre el mensaje. "Error de Conexion".

Cabe mencionar que el web Service, solo coloque ejemplos de Conexión, la info correcta me la reservo, pero lo que vale es la sintáxis.

Desde Ya gracias por el Apoyo Comunidad!!!!

Comment: Desde ya Gracias por el Apoyo

Comment: Puedes mostrar el codigo de tus dos actividades?

Comment: Ok!! con gusto...En breve

Comment: De cual actividad a cual actividad es que quieres enviar el foco.

Comment: Gracias David!!... Pues primer lugar es mi error no haber colocado al comienzo el nombre de la Actividad.... El primero se llama Reporte tiene extensión con la misma Activiad y quiere ir Aplicacion. Considero que se pierde el foco, primer lugar por el mensaje del LogCat. Segundo cuando selecciono cualquier spinner de la actividad Nueva manda el mimo mensaje en LogCat.

Comment: Para ser mas Claros quiere ir de Reporte a Aplicacion... y tengo una opciòn que comenta que "Error conexion", y lo muestra